# Kubernetes UI unreachable

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I followed [this](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config/) guide on configuring Kubernetes on Fedora master-node, everything goes ok, but when I go for UI, I had nothing and couldn't install as described in [this](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/) guide,  so I created

```
{
  "kind": "Namespace",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kube-system"
  }
}
```

and install as

```
 kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml --namespace=kube-system
```

which installed fine, but now when I go for

```
https://<my-ip>:8080/ui
```

I get

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/extensions",
    "/apis/extensions/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/logs/",
    "/metrics",
    "/resetMetrics",
    "/swaggerapi/",
    "/version"
  ]
}
```

and trying to use

```
http://<my-ip>:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
```

for access and get

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

and don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

**Update 1**
Confirmation that plugin installed

```
root@fed-master ~]# kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   1         0         0            0           2h
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   10.254.154.193   nodes         80/TCP    2h
```

**Update 2**

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get ep kubernetes-dashboard
```

gives

```
NAME                   ENDPOINTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   <none>      4h
```

so the question now, how can I set endpoint by myself?

Comment: What does `kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard --nampspace=kube-system` give you? Does `kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard --nampspace=kube-system` show that there is 1 replica running successfully?

Comment: @RobertBailey look update, seems to me like working fine

Comment: Retrieve the logs of the dashboard and if necessary create the endpoint yourself

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen how should I do that? I tried via ARGS variable but failed

Comment: Getting the logs: `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system`

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I get "Error from server: pods "kubernetes-dashboard" not found"

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen look at update 2

Comment: List your pods and replace the pod name please (I could have said that the first time around)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115899/discussion-between-sigrlami-and-norbert-van-nobelen).

Comment: Change the pod name in the @NorbertvanNobelen comment, and show us the logs in details. I hit it recently, and the log show me that the connection to the 127.0.0.1:8080 is refused. A weird problem :-/

Comment: @Sigrlami Did you ever figure out a solution to your problem?

Comment: @fbt no, I moved to cloud solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very new in Kubernetes, but I just had the dashboard work for me in a local VM cluster, so I'll share my recent experience, just in case it's helpful.

I installed it, like you did, using

```
kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

which gave me this output:

```
deployment "kubernetes-dashboard" created
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32548) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.2/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "kubernetes-dashboard" created
```

So I access it via browser using master's IP address, and the port stated in the output, like:

```
http://<kube-master-IP>:<port>
```

In my case, it's:

```
http://172.17.4.101:32548
```

However I did it on my machine, so, as also stated in the output above, mind that:

> If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
>   need to set up **firewall** rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32548) to
>   serve traffic.

Comment: It's first thing I've tried, and it doesn't work for me. I don't have firewalls installed in cloud VM, and all ports are open, so not sure why you have successful run..

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Interestingly, it was in fact running in port 4194. I did netstat -planet|grep LISTEN and tried all the ports listening. When I got to 4194, I got the dashboard. So everything was working. You just have to configure it properly to route to the port you want.